# Color coding in Python f-strings

Tags: listings, strings, python

Since Python 3.6, released Dec 2016, there is new f-string formatting, where, inside your string you can put python code to be evaluated in `{}`s.  It's fantastic but TeX packages for code listings with syntax highlighting don't know about it, or do they?

**MWE:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{cCodeString}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{cCodeKeywordstyle}{RGB}{150,0,150}
\definecolor{cCodeComment}{RGB}{63,127,95}

\lstset{language=python,
    columns=fullflexible,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{cCodeKeywordstyle}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{cCodeComment},
    stringstyle=\color{cCodeString},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
name = "Ann"
print(f"{name}, you have {len(name):4} characters in your name.")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be so good if the stuff inside the `{}` looked like code because the interpreter sees it as code.

Comment: Because your question was sent to the close queue as *unclear* I decided to edit it to make the connection to LaTeX clearer: I assume you want to ask about syntax highlighting in packages like `listings` (one tag you used) or `minted`. If that is not the case or I got anything else wrong, please feel free to roll back the edit, but please make sure to reformulate your question afterwards to avoid confusion. On first glance the question could have been read as asking about Python and not about LaTeX at all.

Comment: Note that the edit by @moewe is not functional Python code – this question refers to "f-string formatting", so for this to actually work, the string needs to be prefixed by `f`, as in `print(f"{name}")`,

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't find an answer using the `listings` package.

However, I reckon the `minted` package understands Python f-strings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
  name = "Ann"
  print(f"{name}, you have {len(name)} characters in your name.")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

which renders as:

[image]

Note, however, that while LaTeX's `minted` package detects the first variable (`{name}`), it fails to detect the second one (`{len(name)}`).

This is actually a problem not of the `minted` package but of the [Pygments](https://pygments.org/) Python lexer, as the `pygmentize` CLI renders it identically. (The `minted` package uses Pygments as its backend.)

I haven't found any solution to this problem yet, but [have created an issue](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1340) at the Pygment's GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  This system wouldn't let me add "latex" as a tag, I guess because the forum is about latex?

Comment: Interesting is that Jupyter Notebooks gets it right.

Comment: Yeah, but they must surely use a more robust syntax highlighting engine. For instance, as far as I know, neither `listings` nor `minted` (Pygments) care if a symbol is actually a variable. If the variable `name` doesn't exist the result is exactly the same. Jupyter does care ---needs to care--- for that.

Answer (score 2):

The extension `piton` detects directly the interpolations in the f-strings of Python. However, `piton` requires LuaLaTeX (but does not require any exterior program).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}

\begin{Piton}
name = "Ann"
print(f'{name}, you have {len(name):4} characters in your name.')
\end{Piton}

\bigskip
\SetPitonStyle{String.Interpol = \color{blue}, Interpol.Inside = \color{gray}}

\begin{Piton}
name = "Ann"
print(f'{name}, you have {len(name):4} characters in your name.')
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]